# Extracting _fini in C binary

Tags: c, elf, objdump

I am basically looking for a way to extract _fini address within a binary. Naive way I can think of is to use objdump and parse for _fini. Is there a better way to do this (e.g. not using objdump).

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you want to tell us what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: I just want to figure out where user program assumes control and where user program end's control (main & _fini)

Comment: Do you want the address from within the program itself, or do you want it from an existing program (i.e. with `nm`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
[karma100@localhost ~]$ nm attackme | grep _fini
080484b0 T __libc_csu_fini
080484ec T _fini
[karma100@localhost ~]$
```